# PHP GET variable with dash

Tags: php, get

The URL is **something.php?id=123-10-1**

If I `echo` it, it only prints out **123** but I need it to say **123-10-1**.

I suppose the solution is very simple but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Indeed, you should have "123-10-1" when you echo $_GET['id'] ...

Comment: Are you sure you're not manipulating the `$_GET` beforehand? As @lpg states, you should be getting "123-10-1" (without any prior manipulation)

Comment: did you use and anchor tag for <a href="something.php?id=123-10-1">?

Comment: I updated my answer, with additional offtopic note - when we already know what was the cause. BR!

Answer (score 2):

Of course, You will have the full argument stored in GET array. You are not doing anything wrong. The mistake should be somewhere else. Try to use:

```
var_dump($_GET);
$equal = ('123-10-1' == $_GET['id']);
var_dump($equal);
```

To see what is wrong... Echo is not the best printing functino here, however, it also should print the full argument...

---

**UPDATE - note**

After we know what was wrong:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : '';
```

I would suggest something like that:

```
// Set part of the code
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ''; 

// Verification part of the code
if (!is_numeric($id) && $id != '') {  
    throw new Exception('ID must be numeric.');
}
if ($id == '') {
    // ID was not set in the url. Maybe there should be another action here?
}
```

IN that case, You are in full control of what is happening here. Modyfing GET values or POST values "on the fly" is not the good practice.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution.

Comment: I just answered it. Seems a bit weird, try it yourself.

Comment: I like that you actually do the check the "safe" way. `value == $variableToCheck` +1 for that :>

Comment: Thx for the comment. This kind of diagnosis is always helpful, when we know what "should be", and "it isn't" :).

Answer (score 2):

Use php [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an anchor tag like `<a href="something.php?id=123-10-1">` and it will echo 123-10-1

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the function [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) which  encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

This was my code.

```
$id = $_GET['id']

echo $id; //123
```

and it printed '123' only.

But

```
echo $_GET['id']; //123-10-1
```

printed it all. Seems weird stuff as it should work in the first place, but it works now.
Gotta check my php.ini to see what's this all about.

Comment: And weren't you modifying $id in the mean time? It is really weird. Please, provide full code as the case is very itneresting :).

Comment: Oh dear, yes I was. Spot on Jacek!

This is what I was doing (somehow I missed the (int) the whole time):
`$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : '';` 

I am so sorry, I just didn't see it before. :( Thanks for helping me out, I probably would've never looked back at it!

Comment: No problem :). There was also a little probaility that after some misplaced code, you will get a result like 111 (123 - 10 - 1 = 111 :P). Best regards, and glad to help.

Comment: I will update my answer, with a little offtopic note in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

- I have try your code it giving me correct response

  -`<?php echo    $_GET['id']; ?>`

Output 123-10-1